# d3: <div> tooltip is displaying the same data on mouseover for all elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, geojson

I'm doing the freecodecamp choropleth map project: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/data-visualization/data-visualization-projects/visualize-data-with-a-choropleth-map

It's a US county map with education data.

Everything is working correctly, except my  tooltip. On mouseover, the tooltip is supposed to display the county name, percentages, etc. In actuality, the info for one single county is displayed regardless of which county the mouse is hovering over in the map.

If I append a d3 title tooltip the data is shown correctly. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the dataset I'm referencing is not the one specified in the `.data(dataset).enter()` call. See selections of my code below, with the problem code noted near the bottom with a comment. Thanks!

```
// Fetch the population/education dataset and feed it into a function that will merge it with the map dataset

fetch("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(popData => dataMerge(popData))

// Merge datasets -- this fetch is for the map geometry data

function dataMerge(popData) {
  fetch("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(geoData => {

      const counties = geoData.objects.counties.geometries;
      popData.forEach(elem => {
        let fips = elem.fips;

        for(let i=0; i<counties.length; i++) {
          let id = counties[i].id;
          if(id === fips) {
            counties[i] = Object.assign(counties[i], elem);
            break;
          }
        }
      })
      return geoData;
    })
    .then(geoData => svgGenerate(geoData))
}

// Generate the svg
function svgGenerate(data) {

  let geojson = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties);
  let statesjson = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.states)
  // let projection = d3.geoAlbers();
  const path = d3.geoPath();

  const canvas = svg.append('g')
    // .attr('padding', padding)
  canvas.selectAll('path')
    .data(geojson.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('class', 'county')

// since I'm using the geojson.features data, I must pull the county data explicitly.

    .attr('data-fips', (d,i)=>data.objects.counties.geometries[i].fips)
    .attr('data-education', (d,i)=>data.objects.counties.geometries[i].bachelorsOrHigher)
    .attr('fill', (d,i) => {
      const percentage = data.objects.counties.geometries[i].bachelorsOrHigher
      if(percentage<10) return 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
      else if(percentage<20) return 'rgb(223, 254, 240)'
      else if(percentage<30) return 'rgb(187, 255, 226)'
      else if(percentage<40) return 'rgb(131, 255, 202)'
      else if(percentage<50) return 'rgb(0, 255, 146)'
      else if(percentage<60) return 'rgb(5, 215, 126)'
      else if(percentage<70) return 'rgb(1, 99, 57)'
      else return 'black'
    })
    .attr('transform', 'translate(160,30)')

// ****** HERE IS WHAT FAILS ******* 

    .on('mouseenter', (e,d) => {
      tooltip.style('visibility','visible')
        .style('left', event.pageX+'px')
        .style('bottom', h-event.pageY+300+'px')
        .html((d,i) => `${data.objects.counties.geometries[i].area_name}<br/>${data.objects.counties.geometries[i].bachelorsOrHigher}%`)
        .attr('data-education',(d,i)=>data.objects.counties.geometries[i].bachelorsOrHigher)
    })
    .on('mouseout', (e,d) => {
      tooltip.style('visibility','hidden')
    })
    .append('title')
    .text((d,i)=>data.objects.counties.geometries[i].fips)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this. Inside the `.on('mouseover', ...)`, the index received from the dataset was always 0 — the d variable referencing only the data of the element that triggered the mouse event. I ended up giving each element a custom "index" attribute from outside the on.mouseover function, and then retrieved it from inside the function with `let index = e.target.getAttribute('index')`